# Prevent end user manipulating URL to change content on website, method GET PHP

Tags: php

I have a personal search site project I'm building, at the moment the only data that is being displayed on the website is data that is retrieved using SELECT queries and the GET method using the super global $_GET['example']. Now I don't know if I'm doing this wrong but some parts of my page are only displayed if certain GET variables in the URL are set or not empty. Below shows how my URL looks

EXAMPLE: **index.php?search_category=guitar&main_category=9&postcode_val1=NP22&distance_default=100&submit=search**

I have a lot of these  **if(isset($_GET['search_category'])** type conditions in my website which are replied upon and show particular parts of content depending  whether or not these are either true or false.

I have been on a lot of other websites that have similar URL's, I have tried to alter and manipulate these and the content does not break, alter or change in any way yet when i try this with my url it breaks my page and only certain parts of content gets displayed by being based on what is set. Is there some other layer of protection I should add, would using something like a rewrite rule help? The code below shows how I have wrote a drop down box based on what has been set In the URL but if a user edits the URL this is easily broken.

```
if(isset($_GET['search_category']) && isset($_GET['main_category']) && 
isset($_GET['postcode_val1']) && isset($_GET['distance_default']))
                        {
                            $stmt = $getFromUi->dispCategories();
                            echo "<option value='0'>All</option>";
                            echo "<option value='#'>-------------</option>";

                            while($row  = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))    
                            {
                                $selected = '';

                                if(!empty($_GET['main_category']) && $_GET['main_category'] == $row->cat_id) 
                                {
                                   $selected = ' selected="selected"'; 
                                }

                               echo '<option value="'.htmlentities($row->cat_id).'"'.$selected.'>'.htmlentities($row->cat_title).'</option>';
                             } 
                        }
```

Comment: Simple - use $_POST instead of $_GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will break because the strict nature of logic you use on your code. The `&&` mark with isset mean any parameter you define not set will not evaluate to true. If the parameter is quite flexible why not `||`.

If you need it to still evaluate all parameter try to do limit first if condition to main determiner. like `$_GET['search_category']` and use the remaining $_GET['other_parameter'] as needed inside the block code of main if.

Comment: solved it, great advice. Being to strict had been counter productive.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a post method, so that this goes through as a request instead. In my experiance, get will only fetch the url you open - not actually pass anything through unless its in the URL.

Not sure if that made any sense, but check post out.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp is a good place to start to see the difference of get vs post.

Comment: That made sense